# How can I replace specific values of all elements in a list

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list `cluster_list` of 11 elements, each element of the same length.

```
 > class(cluster_list)
[1] "list"
```

Each element looks like the example element 2:

```
head(cluster_list[[2]][,1:15])
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15
765   t  t  t  c  t  t  a  a  a   a   c   a   t   a   a
7319  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -   -   -   -   -   -   -
8335  t  t  t  c  t  t  a  a  a   a   c   a   t   a   a
7162  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -   -   -   t   c   t   a
7382  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -   -   -   -   -   -   -
7244  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

I want to remove/change all `"-"` to `""` for all 11 elements in the list

I know how to do it in a matrix:

```
matrix_new <- matrix_old[matrix_old=="-"] <- ""
```

Or how to remove a column of a element in a list:

```
cluster_list <- lapply(cluster_list, function(x) x[!(names(x) %in% c("X1"))])
```

But I´m unable to remove `"-"` from the list. (I´m new to using `list` and the `lapply` function)
Any suggestions to make it look like:

```
> head(cluster_list[[2]][,1:15])
     X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15
765  "t" "t" "t" "c" "t" "t" "a" "a" "a" "a" "c" "a" "t" "a" "a"
7319 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "" 
8335 "t" "t" "t" "c" "t" "t" "a" "a" "a" "a" "c" "a" "t" "a" "a"
7162 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "t" "c" "t" "a"
7382 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "" 
7244 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
```

thx
K

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can loop through the `list`, and use `replace`, to change the values that are `-` to blank (`''`)

```
cluster_list_new <- lapply(cluster_list, function(x) replace(x, x== '-', ''))
```

Comment: the function replace all `"-"` to `<NA>` I think this will solve the problem. Thank you!!

Comment: @KonradWeber  Not sure why it replace to `NA`, perhaps you have a `factor` class?

Comment: Yes, it is `factor`

Comment: And the `NA` actually causing trouble, as I would like to convert the list in the next step into `fasta` format. I thought handle it as a matrix `cluster_matrix <- as.matrix(cluster_list_new)` and than replace `cluster_matrix_new <- lapply(matrix_list, function(x) replace(x, x== '-', ''))`would help. I still get `NA` . I guess the `factor` class is the problem? But how to solve it?

Comment: @KonradWeber  Can you check the class by `class(cluster_list[[1]])` and `str(cluster_list[[1]])`.

Comment: Its class `dataframe` and `Factor`

Comment: Actually, for later use it would be better to convert the `cluster_list` directly into a `fasta` format. Or directly into a `DNAStringSet`. As I want to perform new alignments for each list element of `cluster_list`. Can I use `lapply` to convert the `dataframe` to `fasta`? Not sure how to write it. (sorry for late replay)

Comment: @KonradWeber. Not sure whether you are using any packages to do the conversion.

Comment: Im using `library("DECIPHER")` and `library("Biostrings")` for DNAStrings and the alignment.

Comment: @KonradWeber  Sorry, I forgot to check your comments.  I haven't used `DECIPHER`